# How to pass a variadic function with different type of arguments as a value in golang?

Tags: function, go, parameters, variadic

I want to pass a variadic function as the parameter of another function.I tried like the following code, but it didn't work.Please give me some of advice.

```
type Action func(args ...any) error

func ActionType(f Action) reflect.Type {
    return reflect.TypeOf(f)
}
func main() {

    f1 := func(int, string) error {}
    f2 := func(int) error {}
    f3 := func() error {}
    fmt.Println(ActionType(f1), ActionType(f2), ActionType(f3)) //error here
}
```

Comment: Note that changing type of `f` to `any` will accept any function type (but not just functions): `func ActionType(f any) reflect.Type {}`.

Answer (score 1):

You're declaring `f1`, `f2`, and `f3` as anonymous functions with types `func(int,string) error`, `func(int) error`, and `func() error` respectively, none of which is `func(...any) error`. To create an `Action` you'd have to do `f4 := func(...any) error { //stuff }` for example. Types are pretty strict in Go, and its variadic functions are basically just syntactic sugar for accepting a single slice argument (as the last arg). Roughly, `func(...any)` equals `func([]any)`, though even these aren't even the same type.

The error messages basically tell you this, though more tersely.

```
./prog.go:18:25: cannot use f1 (variable of type func(int, string) error) as type Action in argument to ActionType
./prog.go:18:41: cannot use f2 (variable of type func(int) error) as type Action in argument to ActionType
./prog.go:18:57: cannot use f3 (variable of type func() error) as type Action in argument to ActionType
```

Icza suggested in the comments one way to make `ActionType()` take any function. Another way that I have used before, and is perhaps a little more type safe, is to make `ActionType()` take a function with no arguments (and return an error, or whatever else you need to return). Then, use a closure to capture the "arguments" for the `Action` func. For example:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type Action func() error

func ActionType(f Action) reflect.Type {
    // call f to perform the action
    err := f()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    // do other things ...
    return reflect.TypeOf(f)
}

// this is essentially the same since Action's underlying type
// is "func() error"
func ActionType2(f func() error) reflect.Type { return reflect.TypeOf(f) }

func main() {
    msg := "hello world"
    number := 42
    action1 := func() error {
        fmt.Println(msg)
        return nil
    }
    action2 := func() error {
        number *= 2
        return nil
    }

    fmt.Println(ActionType(action1))
    fmt.Println(ActionType(action2))
    fmt.Println(ActionType2(action2)) // doesn't modify number
    fmt.Println(number)
}
```

Output

```
hello world
main.Action
main.Action
func() error
84
```